# How to send file correctly using resteasy in angular?

Tags: angular, rest, file, resteasy

I have the current service in an angular 5 app:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' })
};

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // file from event.target.files[0]
  uploadFile(url: string, file: File): Observable<any> {

    let formData = new FormData();    
    formData.append('upload', file, file.name);                
    return this.http.post(url, formData, httpOptions);        
  }
}
```

And I have resteasy method in the java application:

```
@POST
@Path("MyThing/Pic")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json")
public void uploadImage(InputStream stream){

    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.available()];
        stream.read(buffer);

        File targetFile = new File("xyz.png");
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        outStream.write(buffer);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO throw!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

The problem is that I need to know the file name in the server side, at least the file name suffix which is the type of the file. If someone upload jpeg I want save jpeg and not png as default for example.
Is there a better way to send the file from 'multipart/form-data' and if yes what should be the definition of the server side method in this case ?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended downloading two jars files:

1. resteasy-multipart-provider-1.1-RC2.jar
2. mail-1.4.jar

Then, I used MultipartFormDataInput in the uploadPhotomethod (the rest service), have a look in the updated method:

```
@POST
    @Path("Company/Logo/{companyId}")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response  uploadPhoto(MultipartFormDataInput input){

        String fileName = "";       
        Map<String, InputPart> uploadForm = input.getFormData();
        InputPart inputPart = uploadForm.get("upload");
         try {

            MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
            fileName = getFileName(header);

            //convert the uploaded file to inputstream
            InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class,null);

            byte [] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);               
            //constructs upload file path           
            writeFile(bytes,fileName);                      

          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        return Response.status(200)
            .entity("uploadFile is called, Uploaded file name : " + fileName).build();
    }
```

And the request header in angular looks like this (removed 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data').

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json' })
};
```

I hope this is helpful for others!